# Gutenberg: How to float core table block in front-end of site?

Tags: block-editor

In the editor, the core table block has a parent div, so it’s easy to float the table to the left or right. In the front-end of the site, this block doesn’t have a parent div, so how can it be floated to the left & right in the front-end, please?

**In the editor there is a parent div and then the figure.**

```
.editor-styles-wrapper .wp-block[data-align=right] {
    position: relative;
}
.editor-styles-wrapper .wp-block {
    max-width: 1000px;
}
.wp-block[data-align=right]>* {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 2em 
} 

<div class="wp-block" data-align="right">
  <figure id="block-f0"  data-type="core/table" data-title="Table" class="block-editor-block-list__block wp-block-table">
```

**In the front-end the core table block doesn’t output a parent div, so how can it be floated to the left or right, please?**

```
.entry-content > * {
  margin: 40px auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

<div class="entry-content">
 <figure class="wp-block-table alignright is-style-stripes">
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `editor-styles-wrapper` to implement layout styling, your table does not have a parent, you need to give it one, not just on the frontend but in the editor too, e.g. a group block

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for commenting. The CSS code above, has been copied from Chrome inspector, I haven't got `.editor-styles-wrapper` in one of my CSS sheets. In the editor, `.<div class="wp-block" data-align="right">` is present,  & it isn't in the front-end. I've checked the Twenty-twenty One theme, & that div is  present only in the editor, as well. Some blocks seem to have wrapper divs only in the editor.

Comment: blocks built using v1 of the block API have a wrapper that only exists in the editor. v2 blocks do not so that they're closer to the frontend markup to be more performant and easier to style with the same CSS. I don't see why you need a containing div to implement this, the editor UI is a special case scenario, can't you just remove that part of the CSS selector or replace it with something specific to your themes frontend? You've already shared HTML code from your frontend that has a wrapping div, why not use that?